# nodejs program running with only node binary

Tags: node.js

To run a node.js program, if I copy only the node binary, then I am seeing that it is working fine. Just wanted to know if I do not install node.js, only copy the node binary in the bin directory, is there any chance that it may not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

On linux or mac, this should be fine.  On windows, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, your best bet for stability is to download the binary directly at http://nodejs.org/download/. Look for Windows Binary (.exe). It will run without installation. This, of course, will not include npm.